# Why does my angular app refresh all rows from the data source when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my first app in angularjs, and I have a problem with the app refreshing all rows from the database whenever I click on a button, even though I haven't asked it to. 
Each row from the data source has a 'block' button. If I click that button, that row in the model is marked as blocked correctly and restyled, but then all the rows are refreshed from the data source, overwriting the change on the client side. Why is this occurring?

Full code:

```
<script>

var bookingAppModule = angular.module('bookingApp',[]);

bookingAppModule.controller('bookingController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.bookingDate = '<%= DateTime.Today.Year %>/<%= DateTime.Today.Month %>/<%= DateTime.Today.Day %>';

    $scope.getAppointments = function () {
        var response = $http.post('/api/Appointments', "'" + $scope.bookingDate + "'" );
        response.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.appointments = data;
        });
        response.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('Something went wrong...');
        });
    };

    $scope.appointments = $scope.getAppointments();

    $scope.blockSlot = function (slot) {
        slot.blocked = true;
    };

    $scope.bookSlot = function (slot) {
        alert("booking slot " + slotId);
    }
}]);


</script>
<div id ="booking-app" ng-app="bookingApp">
<div id="service-select">
<label for='<%= ddlService.ClientID %>'>Select service:</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlService_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="false" >
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div ng-controller="bookingController">
    <input type="date" ng-model="bookingDate" ng-change="getAppointments()" />
    <div class ="appt-day">
    <div ng-repeat="shift in appointments">
    <div class="appt-counsellor">
        <h2>{{shift.counsellor}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat ="slot in shift.slots" class="appt-row clearfix" ng-class="{'blocked' : slot.blocked}" >
        <div class="appt-time">{{slot.time}}</div>
        <div class="appt-desc">{{slot.clientName}}</div>
        <button class="appt-btn mla-button" ng-class="{'show' : !slot.blocked}" ng-click="bookSlot(slot)">Book</button>
        <button class="appt-btn mla-button" ng-class="{'show' : !slot.blocked}" ng-click ="blockSlot(slot)">Block</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on button click you rewrite your $scope.appointments, and 'blocked' property does not save. 
For solve this, you can store 'blocked' property locally in other array and on calling $scope.getAppointments write this property to every 'appointments' object. 
Another way, refresh only appoitments, that has change on server - and your 'blocked' property will saved.

Comment: I see, so because I changed something in the model, and that part of the model is associated with getAppointments(), it automatically calls that function again... So I'd need to keep a separate local copy of the data and then handle writing changes back to the database 'manually' if I don't want the flicker effect of all the rows updating, right?

Comment: Actually, on further investigation, this doesn't fix it. What happens is that after the blockSlot function is called, the whole initialization code in the controller is run, thus resetting the date and retrieving the appointment data again. I have no idea why this occurs.

Comment: Can you create sample plunker for this? You can replace api calls with $httpBackend. I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks - I worked it out. It seems that by default clicking a 'button' element causes a page refresh. I changed the elements to inputs and the problem went away. Thanks again for your help.